# Comparing list elements to a predicate

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I need to construct a a predicate compare_to_predicate/3. It takes in a given predicate and list of numbers and proceeds to compare every element in the list using that predicate.
The given predicates are
- is_odd
- is_even
- greater_than(X)
For example:

```
?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [is_odd], X).
X = [13, 1].
?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [greater_than, 10], X).
X = [13, 500].
```

What I have come up with thus far is:

```
is_odd(X):- 1 is mod(X,2).
is_even(X):- 0 is mod(X,2).
greater_than(X,Y):- X<Y.
compare_to_predicate([],_,[]).
compare_to_predicate([H|Tail],Functor,[H|X]):- Term =.. [Functor,H], Term, compare_to_predicate(Tail,Functor,X).
```

I have a number of issues:

1)

```
?- compare_to_predicate([2,10,8,300],is_even,X).
```

will produce

```
X = [2, 10, 8, 300].
```

but

```
compare_to_predicate([2,10,8,301],is_even,X).
```

will produce

```
false.
```

I assume it has to do with the predicate encountering a number that will not return true on is_even and then terminating the whole compare_to_predicate with a false. In that case is the solution to somehow make it ignore odd numbers instead of evaluating them? If so, how would I do that?

2)

<s>It seems that the given predicate I pass into compare_to_predicate has to have the type List as seen in</s>

```
?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [is_odd], X).
```

<s>and</s>

```
?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [greater_than, 10], X).
```

<s>I am currently simply passing a normal predicate into the Term. I'm not quite sure on how I'm supposed to do that</s>.
It seems that `compare_to_predicate([H|Tail],[Functor],[H|X]):- Term =.. [Functor,H], Term, compare_to_predicate(Tail,[Functor],X)`
did the trick here. Finally:

3)

```
?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [greater_than, 10], X).
```

It seems I need to make compare_to_predicate able to take in predicates with different arity as shown here. Is the solution supposed to be something like this?

```
(Term =.. [Functor,A]; Term=.. [Functor,A,B]).
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you could use `=../2` in conjunction with `call`. You don't need to "hard code" your list elements to, for example, `[Functor, A, B]`. Just use the list. So if `L = [greater_than, 10]`, then `Term =.. L` results in `greater_than(10)`. Then `call(Term, X)` results in `greater_than(10, X)`. This probably has the reverse sense than you desired for argument ordering, but you can deal with that.

Comment: @lurker there's no need to build the term with `=../2`, you can just do `call(is_even, 20)` or `call(greater_than(10), 20)` and it will do the right thing.

Comment: Regarding question 1, what should X be if the odd values are ignored?

Comment: @DanielLyons yeah, you're right. I was just fixated on assuming the OP had them in list form to begin with, but that's not necessarily so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind of need to decide what `compare_to_predicate/3` is supposed to do with values that fail the goal. I see basically three ways this can go:

1. It can behave as a filter, and the third argument is unified with the values in the first argument that pass.
2. It can behave as a for-all, and the third argument is unified with the whole list if they all pass and fails otherwise (your current behavior)
3. It can behave like an for-each that just applies the predicate to each item in the list and discards the result. There is no meaningful value for the third parameter in this case.

By the way, the term surgery you're doing with `=../2` is not necessary; `call/N` will do the right thing if you do something like `call(greater(10), 20)`, so you can just allow the user to call your predicate like this: `compare_to_predicate([1,2,3,4], greater(2), X)` and use call to build the goal.

Doing the first one is pretty straightforward:

```
filter([], _, []).
filter([X|Xs], P, Result) :-
    filter(Xs, P, Xs1),
    (call(P, X) -> Result = [X|Xs1] ; Result = Xs1).
```

Doing the second one is also pretty straightforward:

```
forall([], _, []).
forall([X|Xs], P, [X|Xs]) :- call(P, X), forall(Xs, P, Xs).
```

Doing the third one is not terribly hard:

```
foreach([], _).
foreach([X|Xs], G) :- once(call(G, X) ; true), foreach(Xs, G).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help thus far, but the specific requirement is that the predicate I pass into compare_to_predicate be in the type of a list as shown in     ?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [greater_than, 10], X). and    ?- compare_to_predicate([8,13,1,500], [is_odd], X). Would it be possible to somehow do calls on lists made out of predicates with different arity?

Comment: @T44v1 if you have a requirement that you must receive a list representation of a goal, then you'll have to reassemble it into a term to call it. But the arity of the term doesn't matter to call; if you have `call(foo(a,b,c), d, e, f)` the effect is the same as `foo(a,b,c,d,e,f)`.

Comment: I tried assembling it into a term like this:    compare_to_predicate([X|Xs], [P], Result) :-
        compare_to_predicate(Xs, [P], Xs1), Term =.. [P],
        (call(Term, X) -> Result = [X|Xs1] ; Result = Xs1).  is_odd and is_even work correctly but greater_than still seems to return false and I don't understand why. This is the last problem so I'll only ask a bit more.

Comment: @T44v1 You're overthinking it; `compare_to_predicate(Xs, P, Xs1) :- Term =.. P, ...`

Comment: I tried using that line and now greater_than just returns false while is_odd and is_even say that they expect a list but were given an atom.. The previous one I used returned true on all but greater_than. Something seems to still be incorrect.

Comment: My bad, it seems that i made a mistake of my own in the previous comment, it seems to all be working now. Thanks a lot.